# trouble uploading image

Tags: google-app-engine

When uploading my application an image is always skipped.  I have tried using the GoogleAppEngineLauncher and from command line.  Either way there are no errors in the log.  The image is a png file and is 267KB in size.  My application is written in python.

Any ideas?

Thanks,

Comment: Why do you think is is skipped?

Comment: The image isn't there. Get a 404 in the browser and I can't navigate it by URL (all other images I can).

Comment: I havent' found any documentation about this but is there a size limitation for static content? The image is pretty big 267KB.

Comment: u need to post some code here. nobody can help you if u only say its not working. explain how you access your images, your folder structure, your app.yaml configuration and whatever else has to do with it.